# Ist es unfreundlich "Du bist schlecht für Herz." zu sagen?

Tags: politeness, culture

Ich bin neu in Deutschland und ich habe eine Freundin. Sie hat sich schlecht gefühlt, als ich "Du bist so süß, schlecht für Herz :)" geschrieben habe, und wir haben uns entschieden eine Umfrage zu machen.

Soll man sowas nicht sagen?

Comment: Was soll es bedeuten? Ich würde es negativ empfinden, auch wenn ich glaube, dass du es anders meinst.

Comment: Servus und willkommen beim Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Du kannst eine [tour] der Seite nehmen. Offen gebliebene Fragen, wie sie funktioniert, sollten im [help] beantwortet werden.

Comment: Kann man machen, aber bitte 'fürs Herz'  analog zu 'für die Zähne'. Oder 'ungesund für mein Herz'.. Ansonsten: Der Ton (oder der Blick) macht die Musik!

Comment: Someone told me once: "Du bist so süß, dass ich von dir Karies kriege." It is similar to EralpBs compliment. As a woman, both compliments sound horrible to me. I would never recommend the use of a negative comparisons for a compliment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sofern ich deinen Text richtig verstanden habe, wolltest du darauf hinaus, dass Sie so süß ist, dass es schlecht für dein Herz ist.

Ich gehe davon aus, dass du hier nur den physischen Aspekt (Zucker <--> Herz) betrachtet hast.

Im deutschen kann "Herz" aber auch für Liebe/Gefühle/Zuneigung und Ähnliches stehen.

Beispiel: "Das geht einem ans Herz" bedeutet, das einen etwas auf Gefühlsebene berührt.

Die Verbindung von "schlecht" und "Herz" kann also unbewusst negative Assoziationen hervorrufen, besonders wenn Bestandteile des Satzes fehlen.

In deinem spezifischen Fall denke ich, dass die Aussage dennoch relativ klar zu erkennen war, einem im ersten Moment jedoch durchaus verschiedene Interpretationen in den Sinn kommen könnten.